# map one to many code first from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having trouble mapping one to many relationship between salesheader and saleslines. I am using Code first from database with entity framework 6.1 with fluent api. One salesheader can have multiple saleslines.

SalesHeader PK is Document Type and No

SalesLine PK is Document No and Line No and Document Type

Document No in SalesLine is foreign key in SalesHeader

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SalesLine>()
            .HasRequired<SalesHeader>(s => s.SalesHeader)
            .WithMany(s => s.SalesLines)
            .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Document_No_, s.Line_No_, s.Document_Type });

public partial class SalesHeader
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Document Type", Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Document_Type { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string No_ { get; set; }

    [Column("Sell-to Customer No_")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Sell_to_Customer_No_ { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalesLine> SalesLines { get; set; }



}
public partial class SalesLine
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Document Type", Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Document_Type { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Document No_", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Document_No_ { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Line No_", Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Line_No_ { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string No_ { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesHeader SalesHeader { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: those variable names are atrocious! who ends a variable with a `_`??

Comment: it is autogenerated code. code first from database from dynamics nav db

Comment: this is unfortunate.

Comment: you should have `HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Document_Type, s.Document_No_ }` according to the declared keys of SalesHeader type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so using Data Annotations, include this in your `SalesLine` class:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("SalesHeader")]
[Column("Document Type", Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Document_Type { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("SalesHeader")]
[Column("Document No_", Order = 1)]
[StringLength(20)]
public string Document_No_ { get; set; }
```